# Will the pg_stat_statements view show old data if there is no transaction going on in the database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pg, pg-stat-statements

I am trying to write a query using pg_stat_statements to find the elapsed time of queries running in the database. I want to know if there are no transactions in the database will the view show only the old data ? When will the data get purged from the view ? I want only those queries which was running in the past few minutes(suggest me an alternate view or any method to achieve this)....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

The statistics collected by and shown in `pg_stat_statements` are cumulative, that is, you see the sum of everything that happened since you installed it or since you last called `pg_stat_statements_reset()` to reset the statistics.

To get meaningful data from `pg_stat_statements`, either regularly reset the statistics, or (better) use a monitoring program like pgWatch2 that regularly takes a snapshot of the data. By calculating the difference between such snapshots you can get data about the workload in that time interval.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I want to make sure about the behavior of the view and I also want some suggestions to get the queries which ran in the last 5 minutes using the same pg_stat_statements view.

Comment: As I said, you cannot get that.

Comment: Is there any way to filter by time ? I want the queries which has ran or running in the past 5 minutes and has higher elapsed time. Can someone suggest me how to do it ?

Comment: No, you cannot get that. `pg_stat_statements` collects aggregated results. I told you to get a monitoring program.